# Run time error '1004': Copy method of worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I want to split workbook by worksheet name but if throws above error after splitting 5 sheets but i have 20 sheets in the workbook. I have used below code and the error happens at xWs.copy.

Please help me fix the error in the code. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Splitbook()
'Updateby20140612
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have code in the worksheet code sheets? Possibly a Worksheet_Change event macro?

Comment: or in xPath there's already some ".xlsx" file named as one of the sheets

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have a hidden worksheet in the queue. In the following, I've stored the original [Worksheet.Visible property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx) value ([XlSheetVisibility Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821673.aspx)), then made the worksheet visible and finally restored the original visiblility state. If it was already visible to begin with, there is no error.

I never recommend that you include a file extension in a [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx)  operation. In fact, I recommend intentionally omitting it and allowing the *FileFormat* parameter and [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) to supply the correct file extension.

```
Sub Splitbook()
    Dim vis As Long, xPath As String, xWs As Worksheet

    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        vis = xWs.Visible
        xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name, _
                                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        xWs.Visible = vis
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you want to skip worksheets that are not visible, add a condition that does not perform the Copy, SaveAs operation if the xWs.Visible property is not **xlSheetVisible**.

If there is code in the worksheet code sheet (e.g. a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro), it will be discarded without acknowledgement due to the [Application.DisplayAlerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx) you have to *False*.

Comment: Or maybe the worksheet name contains characters that not allowed in file name like: `< " > |`.

Comment: I had similar thoughts but the characters that are not allowed in a worksheet name closely parallel the characters that are not allowed in a file name. For the time being, I thought I would go with this. I'll do a character-by-character comparison of the two reserved character sets if this turns out to be the next problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem too because invisible worksheet.
I made a different solution to SKIP invisible worksheet instead.
Wrap the copy code in an IF statement

`If xWs.Visible Then *docodehere* End If`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the workbook you are splitting gets activated, and because it contains macros it couldn't be saved as xlsx.

Try to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before your `For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` and after the cycle `Application.EnableEvents = True`