# Using VB6 to copy worksheet from one workbook to another - works intermittently

Tags: excel, vb6

Here is my code. I am using this in two different programs but reading from different xls template files.  In one program this works fine. In the other, I get an error:

> 1004, "Copy method of Worksheet class failed

Both files are open and visible so I can see what its doing. "ThisWorkBook" has three tabs, and I'm trying to insert the tab from "MyBook" after the first tab in "ThisWorkBook".

Its the .copy after command that's throwing the error. Anyone have ideas as to why it works in one instance and not the other?

```
TempString = Open_ExcelObject(Excel_Object, XLTempDir & XLTempName) 'create Excel_Object if needed and open file
Excel_Object.Visible = True
Set thisWorkBook = Excel_Object.ActiveWorkbook
Set thisWorkSheet = thisWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
TempString = Open_ExcelObject(Excel_Object, XLInitialDir & XLTemplateNM) 'open template file
Set MyBook = Excel_Object.ActiveWorkbook
MyBook.Sheets(TabName).Select 'select desired tab to copy from template

MyBook.Sheets(TabName).Copy After:=thisWorkBook.Sheets(1) 'copy tab from template file after first tab in temp file

MyBook.Close 'close template (without save)

TempString = SaveAndClose_Excel(Excel_Object, XLTempDir & XLTempName, True) 'Close temp file WITH save

TempString = Open_ExcelObject(Excel_Object, XLTempDir & XLTempName) 'reopen temp file with the template tab now included
```

Comment: Are you running this in Excel?  Are you using VB6, or VBA?  I would not use ThisWorkbook as a variable name in Excel.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: willvv: As stated in the original poset, the error is  #1004, "Copy method of Worksheet class failed".

Comment: Tim: I am using VB6.

Comment: Perhaps you can get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812806/run-time-error-1004-copy-method-of-worksheet-class-failed

Comment: Justin, that would work to split out worksheets into separate files. I need to insert a worksheet after a specific tab in an existing file. Also, I am using the older Excel 2003 (with .xls file format) as our other software is not compatible with the later version of Excel that uses the .xlsx format.

Comment: HMMM.. Maybe I can copy the worksheets I need from the two files in order into a new third file.Or maybe not try to insert it in a specific spot, just copy in the remplate worksheet, save it then re-open and re-arrange the tabs as needed.

Comment: I meant you can use that other discussion to see why your code is failing, not that you should use the methods to split the worksheets into separate files.

Comment: Could be a timing issue.  I would suggest try inserting `Sleep` calls between each line of code to see if that gets rid of the error.  See http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7556